# Getting Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Build info: version:'2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac'

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

After editing I have to click on "Ok" button and for which I have given a correct xpath, when the automation is performed at the time of clicking on "Ok" it shows an error for "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Build info: version:'2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac'". Please help to resolve it, below are the code:

```
public class Ins {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        File file= new File("E:\\abc\\eclipse\\installed\\firefox.exe");
        FirefoxBinary binary= new FirefoxBinary(file);
        FirefoxDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver(binary, new FirefoxProfile());

//      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("URL");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        // Verify the insfocus system center page has been opened or not by
        // xpath//

        if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/h1")) != null) {
            System.out.println("InsFocus BI System Center has been opened");
        } else {
            System.out.println("InsFocus BI System Center is not displaying");
        }

        WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
        userName.sendKeys("pr");

        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
        password.sendKeys("123456");

        WebElement signIn = driver
                .findElement(By
                        .xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/form/center/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/input"));
        signIn.click();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        // Verify that welcome page is displayed or not//

        WebElement welcomePageVerify = driver
                .findElement(By
                        .xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[2]/span"));
        if (welcomePageVerify.isDisplayed()) {
            System.out.println("Welcome page is displaying");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Welcome page is not displaying");
        }

        // Try to click on the tab name "Settings" by xpath//

        WebElement settings = driver.findElement(By
                .xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/ul/li[3]/a"));
        settings.click();

        // Verifying that after clicking on "Setting" it opens a database page
        // or not//

        WebElement settingsVerify = driver
                .findElement(By
                        .xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/h1/span"));
        if (settingsVerify.isDisplayed()) {
            System.out
                    .println("Database page is displayed after clicking on Setting tab");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Database page is not displaying");
        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        // Click on the button "Users" by xpath, so that it goes to the page
        // where it show the list of users //

        WebElement users = driver
                .findElement(By
                        .xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/p/a[2]"));
        users.click();

        // Verifying for users page opened or not//

        WebElement usersPageVerify = driver
                .findElement(By
                        .xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/h1"));
        if (usersPageVerify.isDisplayed()) {
            System.out
                    .println("Users page is displayed after clicking on users button");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Users page is not displaying");
        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        System.out.println("Total time take " + new Date());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in wait");
        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Total time take " + new Date());

        WebElement usUserName = driver.findElement(By.id("gs_UserName"));
        usUserName.clear();
        usUserName.sendKeys("Pra13");
        usUserName.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in wait");
        }
        usUserName.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
        System.out.println("Total time take " + new Date());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in wait");
        }
        /*
         * Actions builder = new Actions(driver); builder.sendKeys(usUserName,
         * Keys.ARROW_DOWN); Action clickEnter = builder.build();
         * 
         * clickEnter.perform();
         */

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        // Checked the checkbox of find elemet or user//
        WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.id("jqg_tblMainTable_243"));
        checkbox.click();

        // After checked the checkbox it enables the edit button for edit the
        // user//
        WebElement editButton = driver.findElement(By.id("btnEdit"));
        editButton.click();

        // ------------Edit user popup--------------//

        // Verify edit popup opened or not//
        String source = driver.getPageSource();
        int a = source.indexOf("Edit User:");
        if (a > 0) {
            System.out.println("Edit user popup is displayed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Edit user popup is not displaying");
        }

        // All the WebElement parameter is located here//

        WebElement euUserName = driver.findElement(By.id("UserName"));
        euUserName.clear();
        euUserName.sendKeys("pra14");
        WebElement euFullName = driver.findElement(By.id("txtFullName"));
        euFullName.clear();
        euFullName.sendKeys("pra14");
        WebElement euPassword = driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword"));
        euPassword.sendKeys("123456");
        WebElement euConfirmPassword = driver.findElement(By
                .id("txtConfirmPassword"));
        euConfirmPassword.sendKeys("123456");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in wait");
        }

        WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("RoleID"));

        // Verify dropdown is displayed or not not //

        if (dropdown.findElement(By.id("RoleID")) != null) {
            System.out.println("Dropdown is displayed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Dropdown is not displaying");
        }
        Select clickThis = new Select(dropdown);
        clickThis.selectByVisibleText("Normal");

        System.out.println("Drop down values "+clickThis.getOptions().get(0).getText());

        /*if (dropdown.findElement(By.id("RoleID")) != null) {
            System.out.println("Dropdown is displayed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Dropdown is not displaying");
        }
        Select clickThis = new Select(dropdown);
        clickThis.selectByVisibleText("Normal");*/

        WebElement euUserDetail = driver.findElement(By.id("UserDetails"));
        euUserDetail.clear();
        euUserDetail.sendKeys("pradeep14");

        WebElement euOk= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/button[1]"));
        euOk.click();
        System.out.println("Ok button clicked");

        }

    }
```

Comment: Try making an invisibleClick(WebElement element) method that does a javascript click on it.  Then you can click elements that are hidden without issue.

Comment: Got the answer actually web page is not loading proper so i have using thread.sleep and its work fine.

Comment: It is discouraged to use Thread.sleep. you should use WebdriverWait with ExpectedConditions to wait for page load.